# Simple Form grouping method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

My "Animal" model is structured as such

```
---------------------------
animal      | animal group
---------------------------
Boxer       | dog
Pomeranian  | dog
Whale       | fish
```

I am trying to use simple form (Rails 4) to create a select box with optgroups that group them by "animal group". How would I go about doing this?

I've tried

```
= f.input :animal_id, :collection => Animal.all, :as => :grouped_select, :group_method => :animal_group
```

I keep getting this error

```
undefined method `map' for "dog":String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for this. In example below, I'm grouping by id and name, but can modify this for your case:

```
<%= f.collection_select :animal_id, Animal.all, :id, :name, {}, { class: "some-juicy-class" } %>
```

Hope this helps!